# Como iterar sobre uma quantidade enorme de registros com scala sorm

Tags: scala, iterator

Quero iterar sobre um monte de registros de uma tabela com o sorm, mas quero fazer de uma maneira eficiente em termos de memória.

Hoje uso esse código:

```
Db.query[Items].whereEqual("title", someTitle).fetch.foreach { webCount =>
          //do something
}
```

O problema é que esse código primeiro carrega todos os registros antes de seguir para cada item no loop. Tem alguma maneira de fazer um stream de registros?

[Link da pergunta original em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267999/how-to-iterate-over-a-huge-amount-of-records-with-scala-sorm)

Answer (score 3):

Os métodos [`Querier.fetch` e `Querier.fetchIds`](http://sorm-framework.org/sorm/current/#sorm.Querier) retornam *streams*, o que não significa que você não possa ficar sem memória caso tenha que trabalhar com todos os objetos retornados ao mesmo tempo.

O objeto [`Query`](http://sorm-framework.org/sorm/current/#sorm.query.Query) (construído pelo [`Querier`](http://sorm-framework.org/sorm/current/#sorm.Querier)) possui propriedades `limit` e `offset` que permitem paginação no sentido tradicional de banco de dados:

```
val itemCount = Db.query[Items].whereEqual("title", someTitle).count()
// Consultas paginadas
Db.query[Items].whereEqual("title", someTitle).limit(10).offset(40).fetch // ...
```

Comment: Eu não preciso trabalhar com todos objetos ao mesmo tempo. O foreach do stream é 'inteligente' ou tenho que usar outro tipo de iterador?

Comment: Daniel, você teria que mergulhar no [código fonte do Storm](https://github.com/sorm/sorm) para ver como ele está construindo essa Stream (existem diversas maneiras de implementar comportamento preguiçoso). Se existe algum tipo de *cursor* retornando entradas blocadas do banco e se você não está ativando nada que vá carregar tudo de uma única vez, acredito que não tenha problema (mesmo assim, tratando de banco de dados tradicionais, uma hora precisamos de paginação no sentido mais tradicional da coisa).

Answer (score 2):

Segundo um [comentário na documentação](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#comment-718750649), o *fetch* das entidades é feito em duas fases:

1. A query com todos os filtros e ordenações é executada no banco de dados, mas recuperando somente o `id` (chave primária) de cada registro.
2. Quando você realmente chega até o item no `Stream` retornado pela query, então a segunda fase ocorre onde os demais campos são lidos.

Então, como a API parece não fornecer algum outro meio de iterar sobre os resultados, este já seria a forma mais eficiente e dificilmente iria estourar a memória.

Entretanto, o comentário é de 2 anos atrás e realmente não sei se ainda se aplica às versões mais recentes.

---

Comentário original:

> Fetching entities in SORM always goes in two phases: first, all your filters - no matter how intricate, - orderings and etc get applied to a single multitable query which fetches just the ids of the matching entities; in the second phase SORM emits multiple queries to actually populate the resulting entities depending on complexity of their structure. Since all the selects of the second phase are by primary keys, they are very cheap. But this area will definitely become a battlefield for all kinds of optimizations in future. Contibution is much appreciated.
>
> There actually was a querier implementation which was doing everything in a single phase: both querying and object population were being done in a single query in the version 0.1.0, - but then it turned out that, due to specifics of how joining tables works, it could fetch a million rows for certain multicollection entities, literally. So, downshifting to a simpler strategy turned out to be inevitable.
>
> The "Stream" thing is there intentionally. It delays the second phase fetching queries and objects population until you actually reach them in the returned Stream. Although this might be a subject to changes in the future.